# Is there a Javascript event that will activate when you snap you window to the left or the right?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to listen to when the Windows window is snapped to the left or right. I'm trying to reset my testimonial section so that it displays the 1st testimonial. I have testimonials which transitions when buttons are clicked.

JS code:

```
// add listener to set the width of the window and make
            window.addEventListener("resize", resetTestimonial);
            
            function resetTestimonial() {
                var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
                var screenwidth = screen.width;
                
                //reset testimonial when screen is set to 1023
                if (windowWidth == 1023) {
                    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                    btn[i].classList.remove("active");
                    }   
                    btn[0].classList.add("active");
                    slide.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
                }
                
                //reset testimonial when screen is snapped to half
                if(windowWidth == screenwidth/2) {
                    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                    btn[i].classList.remove("active");
                    }   
                    btn[0].classList.add("active");
                    slide.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
                }
                
                //reset testimonial when screen is snapped to Full
                if(windowWidth == screenwidth) {
                    for(i=0;i<4;i++){
                    btn[i].classList.remove("active");
                    }   
                    btn[0].classList.add("active");
                    slide.style.transform = "translateX(0px)";
                }
            }
```

The `if(windowWidth == screenwidth/2) {` doesn't work since the screen isn't 100% the same size and I do not want to check it a few times since then it will reset the whole time when the screen is manually resized.

So I am looking for something like `window.addEventListener("resize", resetTestimonial);` but one that will fire when the window is snapped either to half or to full please.

Thank you!

Comment: The resize event will fire continuously as a window is resized... you're probably better off to just trigger a delayed event after the resizing has stopped. You'll want to look into using a "debounce" function that waits for some "cool off" period to expire before calling your resetTestimonial function.

Comment: Such a `snap` event does not exist, but you can try comparing the `window.outerWidth` and `window.outerHeight` with the `screen.width` and `screen.height` to see if the window is half the screen.